# CodeIgniter can't Login in the first time

Tags: codeigniter

I'm new in CI. I just created login form in CI, Every first time I open my browser and login to the form it doesn't redirect to the page according to the action even the password & user are correct. it's only refresh the page. but the second time I do the login, it works fine.
I have trying with different browser and using incognito doesn't help either. So the error only occurs the first time I running the script.
any ideas?

Thanks

here's the view:

```js
< script type = "text/javascript" >
  $(function() {
    $("#login_form").submit(function(evt) {
      evt.preventDefault();
      var url = $(this).attr('action');
      var postData = $(this).serialize();
      $.post(url, postData, function(o) {
        if (o.result === 1) {
          window.location.href = '<?=site_url('
          dashboard ')?>';
        } else {
          alert('Invalid login');
        }
      }, 'json');
    });
  }); <
/script>
```

```html
<div class="row">

  <div class="span6">

    <form id="login_form" class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="<?=site_url('api/login')?>">
      <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label">Login</label>
        <div class="controls">
          <input type="text" name="login" class="input-xlarge" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label">Password</label>
        <div class="controls">
          <input type="password" name="password" class="input-xlarge" />
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="control-group">
        <div class="controls">
          <input type="submit" value="Login" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" />

        </div>
      </div>

    </form>

  </div>
</div>
```

And here's my controller:

```html
<?php
public function login()
    {                
        $login = $this->input->post('login');
        $password = $this->input->post('password');
      
        $this->load->model('user_model');          
        $result = $this->user_model->get([
            'login' => $login,
            'password' => hash('sha256', $password . PASX)
        ]);
                
        $this->output->set_content_type('application_json'); 
        
        if ($result){
            $this->session->set_userdata(['user_id' => $result[0]['user_id']]);            
            $this->output->set_output(json_encode(['result' => 1]));
            return false;
        }        
            $this->output->set_output(json_encode(['result' => 0]));
        
    }
```

Comment: show the code. Then i can help.

Comment: @ChaitanyaDesai I add the code to the post.

Comment: Instead of === try to used == in if condition.

Comment: @ChaitanyaDesai same result, I need 2nd try to login successfully, but I noticed something. the first time I open my browser and put the url "localhost/testproject" then login, the page refresh itself to http://[::1]/testproject/ and the login failed, the second login on the new url works.
So I try to open that 2nd URL directly the first time I open my browser and do the login, it works that way.
what possibly caused it? (I'm using xampp v 3.2.2)

Comment: You shouldnt need to use site URL for your action. Just use the controller and method.  echo form_open("/checkin/legal")?> Use an array in for the classes. Read the manual. WHen you use echo form_open your form is protected